# How to custom widget like this? A Spinner? A submenu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-spinner, android-holo-everywhere

I want a widget like this on the action bar:

[image]

How can I custom the widget on the actionbar using holo everywhere or actionbarsherlock?

When clicked the **Modify** or the **FaceBook** Item, the **Name** text do not change, just like a menu.

A spinner or a button with dropDownItems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the action bar list navigation mode which uses a `Spinner`. [Here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ListNavigation.java) is a simple example from the ActionBarSherlock samples.

To have a static text at the top, you have to create your own `Adapter` to override `getView()`. There you inflate a layout with an image and the text "Name" and return it for all positions.

Comment: Hello，I'm new on Android.As you say,can I use listnavigation mode + Override ArrayAdapter(override the getView and getDropDownView method),but in actionbarsherlock or holoeverywhere the listnavigation will lose theme,can u give me a demo?many thanks.

Comment: Hello,matthias,I got another problem,the onPrepareOptionsMenu method not called in my Fragment sub class(this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
) while using HoLo Everywhere.

Comment: The fact that I did not answer your extra questions does not justify unaccepting the answer. It is 100% correct and has nothing to do with your further problems with themes and fragments. You will have to create new questions for these issues.